# Security rules causes always getting "Permission denied"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I feel like there is something wrong with Firebase 3 Security Rules.

My rules look like this:

```
{"rules":
  {
    "pages": {
      ".read": true,
      "$pageId": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "root.child('adminUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)"
      }
    },
    "adminUsers": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```

Trying to add set a page object

```
firebase.database().ref('/pages/-KL1TmkWWNUYsMqvTw1E').set({slug: 'rule'})
```

Got this error (even though `/adminUsers/-XXXX = true` where -XXXX is my user id):

> FIREBASE WARNING: set at /pages/-KL1TmkWWNUYsMqvTw1E failed: permission_denied

After changing `".write": "root.child('adminUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)"` to `".write": true`, it worked. But that's not what I wanted.

Tested the same thing with Rules simulator, everything's ok. I'm lost.

Comment: Can you show us some data of your tree so we can see exactly how it is structured? You have an **export to JSON** option on the database tab to make it easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @adolfosrs for asking me to export the db to JSON

I found that I wrap the userId with quotes, and it caused the problem

```
{
  "adminUsers" : {
    "\"9hIokhGbBDfcvdQAPIoM7QcDS3g5\"" : true
  },
  "pages" : {
    "-KL1TmkWWNUYsMqvTw1E" : {
      "slug" : "xxx"
    }
  }
}
```